# Best practices for efficient Bazel builds when using Git worktrees

Tags: git, bazel, git-worktree

I used the "worktrees" feature of git to manage branches of my repo.  This means that every active branch sits in its own directory, and switching branches is accomplished by switching directories.

Unfortunately, this seems to interact badly with bazel.  Even with a shared disk cache, I find that bazel re-downloads remote repositories from my WORKSPACE file for each worktree directory (possibly because of remote actions).  Some of these are quite large and slow to fetch.  (I could install a squid proxy, but I feel like bazel's cache should be sufficient).

I've already found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/dS9UQOK5bec), but no solutions.

I'm sure other users are using bazel and git worktrees solution.  What advice can other users offer?  What bazel configurations have other users found to ameliorate this situation?

Answer (score 1):

For different branches, sharing an output base will be fine. Set [--output_base](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--output_base) to some shared folder, like `bazel --output_base=my_output_base build //...`. You can make it automatic by adding a line like `startup --output_base=my_output_base` to an applicable [bazelrc](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/guide.html#bazelrc).

Do note that this will prevent concurrent builds in different folders. They will queue up and run one at a time instead.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this, and compare it to other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of a remote build cache

You can spin up your own local instance_ via:

```bash
sudo docker run -u 1000:1000 -v ~/bazel_remote_cache:/data \                       
        -p 9090:8080 -p 9092:9092 buchgr/bazel-remote-cache
```

You can set up a home RC file (`.bazelrc`) to use the remote build cache:

```bash
cd ~
echo "build --remote_cache=http://localhost:9090" >> .bazelrc
```

If you do a build now the remote cache is used.

When switching branches a lot of stuff should be already cached. The remote cache works better here than the local cache from my experience.